# NFC to BT/BLE handover with Android 9 now blocking MAC Address retrieval

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

Google now blocking developers from retrieving local Bluetooth adapter MAC address. This is a critical phase for classic NFC to BT/BLE handover process (when both sides are Android phones). Also, it seems that Google is now randomizing MAC address of wireless adapters. How can we overcome this decision? is there an alternative?

I tried fetching the MAC address but there's no official API for that and it seems Google has blocked developers from accessing the MAC.

```
In Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher, local device MAC addresses, such as Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, aren't available via third-party APIs.
```